# Are there any unbiased but inconsistent estimators that are commonly used?

Tags: econometrics

It is well-known that IV estimators (among others) are biased but consistent. I am just curious if any commonly used estimator is unbiased but inconsistent. I realize there may be a distributional assumption that needs to be imposed to get such an example.

More context: I've seen examples of unbiased but inconsistent estimators of the form "only estimate with the first $b$ observations in a sample of $n$, and hold $b$ fixed as $n$ goes to infinity". I can't imagine anybody actually doing this in real life, and I'm hoping to find a more realistic example.

Comment: Looking at the most recent observation as the estimate of future values would be inconsistent for iid random variables but is commonly done.

Answer (score 2):

One example that may occur is with fixed effects. Sometimes, we do run regressions like:
$$
y_{i,t} = \alpha_i + X_{i,t} \gamma + \varepsilon_{i,t}.
$$
Here, $i$ is for example a firm identifier and $t$ represents time and $X_{i,t}$ are firm and time varying covariates. If the number of time observations is fixed, but the number of firms goes to infinity, then although $\gamma$ is consistent, the estimator of $\alpha_i$ will not be consistent, but it will (usually) be unbiased. See also [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/48426/28130) for a related discussion.

Comment: That is surprising to me. I have always been under the impression that the fixed effects $\alpha_i$ are used as controls to ensure the consistency of $\hat \lambda$. Obviously, it comes down to the definition of 'using an estimator' because simply running a regression as mentioned does not amount to using the estimator of $\alpha_i$ because usually one does not base one's conclusions on the estimates of the fixed effect but instead on $\hat \lambda$.

Comment: Yeah, okay, I'm familiar with this, it just hadn't occured to me. As Jesper wrote, I think of this as an estimator of $\gamma$.
You are right though if you assume $N\rightarrow \infty$ with $T$ fixed. If $T\rightarrow \infty$, then the example doesn't work.

Thanks!